# How to add assemblies for multiplatform development?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cpu-architecture

I am developing project using separate assemblies for x86 and x64 platform. How can I add this assemblies to visual studio project to be able to compile solution for x86 and x64 also, without replacing libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the project file manually and change the references like this

```
<Reference Include="YourAssembly" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release32'">
  <HintPath>PathTo32BitAssembly\YourAssembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="YourAssembly" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release64'">
  <HintPath>PathTo64BitAssembly\YourAssembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Thanks. At the end I have used this: <Reference Include="sapnco" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
      <HintPath>..\libs\sapnco\x86\sapnco.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="sapnco" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
      <HintPath>..\libs\sapnco\x64\sapnco.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>